# Make *** no existe el fichero o el directorio .Alto

Tags: linux, make, wifi

Sé que hay mucha información en internet sobre este mismo problema pero intente casi todo.

Estoy intentando instalar un driver para la placa de red RTL8723DE tengo las instrucciones, clona en git, accedo a la carpeta correctamente y cuando hago make me sale que `no existe el fichero o el directorio .Alto`

Ya instale gcc, instale build-essential.

En la carpeta llamada `rtlwifi_new-extended` hay un archivo `Makefile` pero el make sigue sin funcionar y el `./configure` tampoco funciona aunque se supone que es para crear esa carpeta `Makefile`

Mí versión de kernel es debían 5.4.8-1kali1

Espero su ayuda gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copiado del README.md:

> Realtek RTL8723DE module for Linux kernel version 5
>
> Install:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b current

dkms add ./rtl8723de

dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

depmod -a

reboot
```

Por lo que leo, no necesitas hacer el típico `./configure make && sudo make install` (compilación "a manivela").
Se instala mediante dkms, que es "un framework que permite construir módulos del kernel de manera dinámica para cada kernel del sistema, de manera organizada y sencilla."
En cualquier caso, me suena raro que el propio núcleo, o algún módulo específico, no disponga de controlador apropiado para esa tarjeta de red.
Puedes confirmar este extremo mediante el siguiente comando:

```
ls -R /lib/modules/$(uname -r) | grep rtl8723
```

que lista de manera recursiva (-R) todos los módulos instalados (que caen la ruta /lib/modules/) para el kernel en uso (uname -r arroja la versión del kernel); De todos los módulos, filtramos con grep, de una manera sencilla, aquellos módulos que contengan la cadena literal "rtl8723" (el nombre del controlador) en cada una de las líneas que arroje el comando ls.
Espero te sirva.
Suerte.